# Setting up compass/sass project

Tags: sass, compass-sass

When I was young I experimented with CSS, and then after a while my peers pressured me into trying SASS. It's been a slippery slope and the pushers have now got me onto Compass.

I don't really understand the difference between the following two commands

1. `sass --compass --watch .`
2. `compass watch .`

As I was having problems with the first command, I tried setting up a Compass project and using the 2nd.

However, this dies saying "`Undefined mixin 'background-image'`". I can get that error to go away by adding an `@import "compass";` at the top of my .scss file. But why would I have to import compass when I'm running the compass command itself?(!) Surely all the libraries are included there? Obviously not.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--compass` flag for the `sass` command is only intended to be a quick way to access the Compass library.  If you actually need to configure Compass, then it is recommended that you setup a Compass project and use the `compass` command (see: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/858).

Compass is more than just a collection of mixins for prefixed properties.  It is an extension manager that happens to have a few extensions by default (compass, blueprint, etc).  Using Compass only grants you access to the [helper functions](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/) (which are written in Ruby) by default.  This is by design:  you include only the items *you* need, not what Compass thinks you need.